# Can NSUserDefaults store multiple different data types?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nsuserdefaults

Such as both a boolean and an integer? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  NSUserDefaults simply operates like an NSDictionary, [but with a few more convenience methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Don't forget to synchronize the data you set after you're done.

Answer (score 1):

Sure! Here are the setter functions for [`NSUserDefaults`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
– setBool:forKey:
– setFloat:forKey:
– setInteger:forKey:
– setObject:forKey:
– setDouble:forKey:
– setURL:forKey:
```

Comment: Great, thanks for listing these for me. It's interesting that you can store a URL?